# What are the differences between plug-ins, features, and products in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, rcp, product

What are the differences? What gets used for which purpose?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

As the **[RCP tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html)** details

> Plugins are the smallest deployable and installable software components of Eclipse.
>
> Each plugin can define extension-points which define possibilities for functionality contributions (code and non-code) by other plugins. Non-code functionality contributions can, for example, provide help content.
>
> The basis for this architecture is the runtime environment Equinox of Eclipse which is the reference implementation of OSGI. See [OSGi development - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/OSGi/article.html) for details.
> The Plugin concept of Eclipse is the same as the bundle concept of OSGI. Generally speaking a OSGI bundle equals a Plugin and vice-versa.

[image: first rcp]

---

The **[Feature Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseFeatureProject/article.html)** mentions

> A feature project is basically a **list of plugins and other features which can be understood as a logical separate unit**.
>
> Eclipse uses feature projects for the updates manager and for the build process. You can also supply a software license with a feature

[image: new feature]

---

Finally, a **[product](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/product.htm)** is a stand-alone program built with the Eclipse platform. A product may optionally be packaged and delivered as one or more features, which are simply groupings of plug-ins that are managed as a single entity by the Eclipse update mechanisms.

[image: Product definition file show the overview tab]

---

So:

**plugins can be grouped into features which can be packaged as one executable unit called product**.

Comment: This is a rather old answer but anyway:I understand what you are saying, but what is the difference between the `Dependencies` tab of the `Feature` project and the `Dependencies` tab of the `Plugin.xml` and the `Dependencies` tab of the `Product`?Would it be possible to explain?

Comment: @user384706 basically, the `Dependencies` tab of the `Product` allows you to list features (group of plugins) *as well as* plugins needed for your product (http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Ffeature_editor%2Fdependencies.htm: "The Dependencies page lists all Required Features and Plug-ins that must be present in the product before the Update Manager installs this feature. If any of these pre-requisites are missing, the feature will not be installed". The `Dependencies` tab of the `Plugin.xml` only lists other needed plugins.

Comment: Thank you!And why is there a dependencies definition tab in `MANIFEST.MF` **and** in `plugin.xml` **and** in `build.properties.xml` of the **same** plugin?I can't wrap my head around this and make random changes to the project

Comment: @user384706 the `MANIFEST.MF` will contained the "resolved" list of needed plugins **at runtime** (see help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Fmanifest_editor%2Fdependencies.htm): "At any time, you can click the add dependencies hyperlink to have `PDE` analyze your code and generate the correct dependencies in your `MANIFEST.MF` file via either the `Require-Bundle` or `Import-Package` headers." So you shouldn't modify directly that part. The `plugin.xml` can only contain the *direct dependencies* (as opposed to *all* dep. in MANIFEST.ML)

Comment: @user384706 this is different from the dependencies in the `build.properties`, which only concern the needed plugins **at compile time**, for building the plugin.