# Eclipse plugins vs features vs dropins

Tags: eclipse, plugins

What is the difference between these things from an Eclipse installation?

- plugins
- features
- dropins folder

What is the correct use of these folders?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I usually use dropins for sharing plugins amongst multiple Eclipse installations.
See [this article](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/2009/06/27/galileo-install-plug-ins-into-eclipse-ide/) for the dropins directory within an Eclipse.

> you can use some different  structures to place the plug-ins into the Dropins folder – I prefer to separate them by domain:

```
/dropins/exampleA/plugins/…
/dropins/exampleB/plugins/…
/dropins/exampleC/eclipse/features/…
/dropins/exampleC/eclipse/plugins/…
```

But I prefer to reference an *external* dropins folder **[through the eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)**.

```
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=C:/jv/eclipse/mydropins
```

---

The `plugins`/`features` directories in Eclipse are the default installation directories for plugin.
For more on the differences between features and plugins, see my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692048/what-is-the-difference-between-plug-in-feature-and-product-in-eclipse-rcp/2692822#2692822):

- you will copy features (declaration of a group of plugins) in the `features` directory
- you will copy the actual plugins themselves in the `plugins` directory.

Within a dropin folder (either the one within eclipse or an external one), you will get back the same `plugins`/`feature` structure.

Comment: you have /dropins in the layout example, but .../mydropins in the configuration line. they are supposed to be the same, right?

Comment: @Ikraav: yes, you can call that directory as you want, as long as it is referenced in the `eclipse.ini`: see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659 : the "`-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory`" option at the end of that file references said directory.

Answer (score 27):

The dropins directory should be used to install a plugin manually. The typical process is that you download a plugin and extract that archive to the dropins directory.

The plugins directory on the other hand is reserved for Eclipse's updater. You should not mess with it manually. Eclipse will store all plugins you install using "Help"->"Software Updates" or "Help"->"Install new software" (depending on your Eclipse version).

Comment: that sounds good, thx... but what about the features/ folder?