# How to copy Eclipse app with it's all projects and space from one Mac into another?

Tags: eclipse, macos, file-transfer

I have a new Mac computer at the office. And I need to copy Eclipse from my home Mac.
I need to keep all the setting and plugins working fine, as on my home computer. Moreover, I need to have all the SVN setting and projects working too.

So, can you suggest the best option how to do it clearly, to have the final result completely the same, as I have on my current home computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Dropbox logo]

**[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)** might come in handy for this kind of synchronization, both for:

- the Eclipse setup it self
- its workspace

Note: I would install plugins in a **[shared dropin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763843/eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins/2763891#2763891)** and synchronized that directory as well.
That way, when you change/update your Eclipse version, all your plugins are still there.

Since your **[eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)** can reference your workspace, with a *relative* path, all you need is to synchronize one folder with in it: Eclipse, the workspace, your projects.

Comment: Yes. But, keep in mind to let it sync completely before your start working. Otherwise, conflicts will happen. BTW, you can use symbolic links (ln -s) on a Mac to sync folders outside the DropBox.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/) to sync my home and work computers and the projects i work on between the two.

In the Dropbox folder I have a 'Projects\' folder this is where I would put my Eclipse start up directory.

Secondly I would move your install directory for eclipse into the dropbox folder. this would sync any plug-ins you install on both machines. I use a PC and mine is located at 'C:\eclipse\'

Comment: So, you mean I should set up my Eclipse working space at dropbox shared folder on my mac? Becuase I'm fimiliar to DropBox. Can you tell more specific, how you do the sync?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you have the directories stored on your existing machine. Also you can have separate source directories per project, or have them stored in the workspace directory.

If you have the projects stored under a particular user (and the workspace folder), then just setup a user with the same name on the new machine and copy the folders to the same location.

If you have them stored in some location off the root, then again it should just be a case of copying the directories directly to the new machine in the same location.