# Changing default plugin installation directory in Eclipse 3.5.2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, plugins

With the new Eclipse 3.5.2 Update manager, I am not able to find, how do I specify installation directory for my plugins. I use it, so that I can manage multiple installation of eclipse, without installation plugins again. Can anybody provide me settings, so that I can specify location for plugin, while installing it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [external dropins folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763843/eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins/2763891#2763891), with the setting (in your **[eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)**):

```
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=C:/jv/eclipse/mydropins
```

Now, the trick is:
If you install a new plugin through Eclipse itself, it will install it directly in its own `plugins`/`features` internal directories.
It is up to you to move those jars in a similar directory structure in your external dropins directory.
So this is not an *exact* solution for your problem, but at least that allows you to isolate those plugins in a shared external directory which will be read by different Eclipse installation on each Eclipse session startup.

Comment: another way, which I found is by running eclipse.exe with some arguments. below is the example:
D:\eclipse352\eclipse.exe -configuration D:\plugins\all\eclipse\configuration
But, I certainly don't want all of the plugins in a folder, it was easy to keep them separate in earlier versions. I hope Eclipse haven't lost this functionality :(

Comment: @Chetan: you can separate them, but within the same external dropin folder, as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763843/eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins/2763891#2763891