# How to copy plugins between two eclipses

Tags: eclipse

I have two eclipse directories, both are Galileo. One has plugin A installed, the another has plugin B. Now I want to have just one eclipse, is it save to just copy the plugins directory from one of the eclipses to the other?

Comment: seanf gave the best answer. AFAIK just copying plugins into directories is not a good approach. Consider making his answer the correct.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'm not sure when it was introduced, but in Eclipse 3.7 you can install plug-ins from another Eclipse installation via the GUI: `File->Import->Install->From Existing Installation`.  You can also transfer the list of update sites.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10494974/14379

Comment: Didn't work for me until I run the new Eclipse as administrator (on Win10). List was empty until then.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but I would recommend using a "[shared dropins directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763843/eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins/2763891#2763891)" to avoid the copy altogether.

Modify tour [eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590) for both installation:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/<myPath>/mySharedDropins
```

Sadly, when you originally install a plugin, you [cannot install it directly in the shared dropins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830999/changing-default-plugin-installation-directory-in-eclipse-3-5-2/2831041#2831041), so at least one copy is still necessary there.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is safe. This is one way (not the preferred one) to install new plugins.

Comment: Ok, so it works. Nice. I guess I can just zip my plugins folder for backup and copy it back to restore it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also install one plugin from another using p2. You add the other installed Eclipse as an update site, and you can select the installed plug-in (after unchecking the categorization).

For update site you the following path: /path/to/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/SDKProfile.profile

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to modifying the *.ini* file is using Link Files in your Dropins folders. The link files are simply text files with the extension *.link*. They contain a single (I think, never tried with multiple) line of text of the form:

```
path=<full path to an external folder>
```

The folder you reference should have two sub-folders: *plugins* and *features*, where you install your plugins. You can install multiple plugins in a single location. You can drop multiple link files, which means, you can maintain sets of plugins and drop them into different Eclipse installations (which is more flexible than using a shared dropins).

More information:

- [More details on link files](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecfeat/#link-ref) (though seriously prehistoric article).
- [Read about links files in P2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started) (not very informative).