# upgrading to Nightly builds of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using the stable version of Indigo - for JavaEE - and I was wondering if I want to upgrade to a nightly build of Indigo is there kind of "update sites" that I enter and upgrade it or I have to download the whole new package of an Indigo nightly builds, then I have to install my all other development plugins which well takes time...so is there any kind of "update site" for nightly builds as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [list of p2 updates site is here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Project_Update_Sites):

> Nightly builds toward 3.8
>   http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.8-N-builds

But that is for 3.8, not Indigo 3.7.
And regarding their natre, they might not be the best choice.

> #### Nightly Builds
>
> Nightly builds are produced every night from whatever has been released into the HEAD stream of the CVS repository.
>   They are completely untested and will almost always have major problems. Many will not work at all.
>   These drops are normally only useful to developers actually working on the Eclipse Project.
>   Because nightly builds are produced in a different way from integration builds, bundles from nightly builds should not be mixed with bundles from other types of builds

A fresh installation is usually safer than trying to modify an existing (and running properly) Eclipse.
For the plugins issue, see "[How to copy plugins between two eclipses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854765/how-to-copy-plugins-between-two-eclipses/2854782#2854782)".

Answer (score 0):

You should check out a continuous integration tool like http://jenkins-ci.org/ or http://hudson-ci.org/, those are more suited to do scheduled builds than eclipse.

Comment: how Hudson is helping my in this question? yes we internally use hudson and jenkins for our builds in .net and java .. but i don't understand how it is helping me for my question

Comment: On re-reading it sounds like you want nightly builds of eclipse indigo and not your codebase.  So, not helpful, sorry :/  Have you checked out eclipse's page: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/N20110726-2000/index.php