# Is there a way to upgrade eclipse and keep all the installed plugins?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I found it tedious to reinstall all the plugin every time upgrade the eclipse.

Answer (score 46):

This is the best option I've found so far.  Dropins directories work, but they're a pain to maintain, because Eclipse wants to install new plug-ins in the Eclipse directory.

I. To transfer your list of [update sites](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10296741/14379):

1. Run your old Eclipse one last time
2. Go to `Window->Preferences->Install/Update->Available Software Sites`
3. Select all update sites (click on one, then **Ctrl-A**), click `Export`, save the file somewhere
4. Run your new Eclipse, select your workspace
5. Go to `Window->Preferences->Install/Update->Available Software Sites`
6. Click `Import`, choose the file from step 3

II. To copy across your old [plug-ins](http://prapicault.blogspot.com/2011/06/from-helios-to-indigo-is-easy.html):

1. In the new Eclipse, select `File->Import->Install->From Existing Installation`
2. Select your old eclipse directory, eg `~/apps/eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64/eclipse/`
3. Select the plug-ins/features you want to install, click `Finish`
4. When it finishes, you can archive/delete your old Eclipse directory

Comment: Working, also on eclipse based spring tool suite. This really ease my pain.

Comment: Didn't work out of the box for me, there were errors complaining about unknown repositories (e.g. _No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.googlecode.cppcheclipse.core,0.9.6.201005161316_) at step II.3

Answer (score 10):

In the latest Eclipse, you can keep all previously-installed plugins by running Eclipse, selecting File → Import…, continuing with Install → From Existing Installation, and then selecting the older Eclipse’s path.

Comment: thanks, that worked great upgrading from juno to kepler, saved me a lot of time!

Comment: then copy Eclipse/dropins files from the older to the newer Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can install plugins into an external directory [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763843/eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins/2763891#2763891). I don't think there is a way to keep plugins installed from inside Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Import and Export of plugins can be used to keep all the installed plugins.

[Plug-in Export](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/export_wizards/export_plugins.htm)

[Plug-in Import](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/import_wizards/import_plugins.htm)