# Where does Eclipse store list of update sites? And can it be copied to another installation?

Tags: eclipse

My Eclipse installation got completely borked and won't start up, so I will likely have to reinstall it (but this is also relevant when upgrading to a new Eclipse version). I want not to have to hunt down all the plugins I had installed. So where does Eclipse store list of available update sites? And if it isn't in plain text, can it be copied into another installation without problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on File->Export->Install (Installed Software Items to File)

**sorry** that I did not notice that your eclipse installation is not working. I don't think there is a direct solution to import the installs from eclipse config files (If you can't export from eclipse). Eclipse stores this configuration in the "articles.xml" files inside "eclipse/configuration/../../...." 
e.g on my box I checked here:
`eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/293/data/-750392822/artifacts.xml`
There will be many articles.xml files like this.                                                    I suggest to find one articles.xml files inside your broken eclipse path and then try importing that in new eclipse by help->install new softeare->(the click on) Available Software Sites->Import and then import these articles.xml files. To be honest, I did not try this, but would like to try this..

Comment: sorry that I did not notice that your eclipse installation is not working. I don't think there is a direct solution to import the installs from eclipse config files. Eclipse stores this configuration in the "articles.xml" files inside "eclipse/configuration/../../...." e.g on my box I checked here:eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/293/data/-750392822/artifacts.xml

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where it stores the websites but you can export/import sites from/to eclipse

There is a link like button named "Available Software Sites" on intall update/plugin window. There you can choose all the sites and export those sites and import on another eclipse installlation.

Comment: Well, I can't export sites because it won't start. Though it may be useful _after_ rebuilding the installation.

Comment: did you change eclipse.ini? is that the reason for eclipse not starting or sth else?