# Eclipse plugin download on desktop to install on another machine offline

Tags: eclipse, installation, plugins, manual

In my work placee, eclipse marketplace access is disabled and i can't access any url from eclipse instead. I need one plugin to install called egradle. It's on the marketplace. I want to download it in my home computer so that i can email it to my workplace to install on my office eclipse. How do i do that?

I am unable to download the plugin

Comment: Well the github site for this seems to be https://github.com/de-jcup/egradle there may be something there

Comment: Install the plug-in at home from the marketplace. Move the plug-ins like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180604/is-there-a-way-to-upgrade-eclipse-and-keep-all-the-installed-plugins/10494974#10494974

Comment: The update site is in [this repo](https://github.com/de-jcup/update-site-egradle) which you can [download as ZIP](https://github.com/de-jcup/update-site-egradle/archive/refs/heads/main.zip), extract it and then install it via _Help > Install New Software..._ working with the `update-site` subfolder of the local extracted ZIP.