# How to export Eclipse 3.5 servers to Eclipse 3.6

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jboss

At work we're planning to upgrade from Eclipse 3.5 Galileo to 3.6 Helios and I'm creating a little migration guide for everyone to use together with all needed configuration files to be imported.
The idea is to do clean install of the new Eclipse version and just use the current workspace and external plugins directory (a per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763843/eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins/2763891#2763891) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830999/changing-default-plugin-installation-directory-in-eclipse-3-5-2/2831041#2831041))

So far it all seems to work fine, I have succesfully exported/imported the libraries, run/debug configurations but I don't seem able to export the various Tomcat and JBoss server configurations i.e. runtime and server definitions. I can only re-create them manually...
Is there a way to export these from the Eclipse GUI or perhaps some metadata or config file somewhere that I can hack?

Thank you and adios,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the special plugin [e4preferences](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/e4preferences/) a go.

It is the only way I know to obtain a fine-grained preferences export.

The only other way is to export everything, and to grep the lines of interest in order to copy those lines in a new preference file, and import that new file.