# Eclipse installation error: java.io.IOException

Tags: eclipse

I tried to install Eclipse Oxygen on my macbook with High Sierra. The installation failed with logs. 
At the end of the log I found:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory /Users/macuser/.p2/pool/plugins.
```

I have my username on the macbook which is different than `macuser`. I'm wondering how to make Eclipse installation or how to tell my mac not create directory inside "macuser" but inside "mycustomser" instead.

Comment: I found this, although im not able to verify if it works https://stackoverflow.com/a/2831041/3266767