# installation "objectaid" feature for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation, diagram

i try to install the feature of diagram  - "objectaid" for eclipe  .. 
i do all the instruction in the mannual in `http://www.objectaid.com/installation` and during the installation i get the error -

```
Unable to read repository at http://www.objectaid.com.
Unable to read repository at http://www.objectaid.com.
http://www.objectaid.com is not a valid repository location.
```

i checked all the prerequisites needed like `GEF (Graphical Editor Framework)` and it was ok .

thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly did you download? I download 4 jars inside features/ folder and pasted them to eclipse/dropins directory but nothing happened after restart. I can not find it installed in my Eclipse. I am using Eclipse Luna.
I also tried downloading objectaid-1.1.8.zip and copied it to eclipse/dropins but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the update site is a legacy update site.  I do not know if they are still supported by Eclipse.

Your best bet is to download the zip of the feature, which you can find here:
http://www.objectaid.com/update/

And then unzip it into your eclipse/dropins directory.

Comment: what i have to do after i unzip to eclipse/dropins directory  ?

Comment: Restart Eclipse.  See this SO post for more information about the dropins directory.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763843/eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins In general, you want to avoid using that way of installing plugins, but your case warrants it because the update site is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The ObjectAid update site does work. I recently added ObjectAid successfully to my Eclipse Mars. I compiled the steps [here](http://evverythingatonce.blogspot.in/2016/04/tech-talk-reverse-uml-generator-in.html). You can try it out. Also, make sure there's no firewall or network issue when you try it.

Comment: Please add some explanation here rather than just the link to steps.