# How to install eclipse color theme plugin without eclipse itself

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I use eclipse at work. Our internet is limited so I can't download plugins through eclipse itself. Anybody know a way I can download it at home, then install it from a flash drive or something of that nature? All I can find is info on the github and I have no idea how to use that. Still a noob

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help any? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371176/downloading-eclipse-plug-in-update-sites-for-offline-installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

Download the github zip file from [here](https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme.github.com/zipball/master)

The dropins directory should be used to install a plugin manually. The typical process is that you download a plugin and extract that archive to the dropins directory.

The plugins directory on the other hand is reserved for Eclipse's updater. You should not mess with it manually. Eclipse will store all plugins you install using `"Help"`->`"Software Updates"` or `"Help"`->`"Install new software"` (depending on your Eclipse version).

Please, let me know if this works for you.

[See the stackoverflow question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763843/eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins)

Comment: nah, didn't do it.  That's not to say it doesn't work at all, I just can't get it to take on my work computer.  Thank you though!