# What is the difference between plugins vs dropins and features?

Tags: java, eclipse, rad

Could Any one give me a clear picture of what is the need to have plugins, dropins and features folders in IBM SDP(Eclipse)?
I found a SOF question @ [Eclipse plugins vs features vs dropins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763843/eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins) but I am not satisfied with the answers listed there.

Comment: What aren't you satisfied with? The accepted answer and the links in the answer seem to cover everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're unsatisfied with.

The features/plugins folders are modified when installing plugins through the "Install new software" in Eclipse. It's the "normal" way to install plugins.

I've only used the dropins folder when trying to share the plugins from another Eclipse folder. It's just to make managing many plugins from many Eclipse installations easier.