# RCP based on plugins or features?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application based on plugins because I started this app from a simple Mail example.

I am now wondering what is the difference between an RCP application based on features compare to one based on plugins ?

For information, my RCP will maybe require some advanced features such as headless build, or self update. May be this can impact on the choice of using plugins or features as basis?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692048/what-is-the-difference-between-plug-in-feature-and-product-in-eclipse-rcp/2692822#2692822 might help here.

Comment: Thanks for this link. Nevertheless i am still wondering what are the impacts of this choice on PDE headless build ?

Comment: fair enough. I have added some elements in a separate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since features are just a collection of plugins (aka, a "packaging" process), you should be able to do in a PDE headless build what you can do with the PDE GUI.

The [PDE build page](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.pde.build/notes/usingPDEBuild.html?view=co) does mention:

> Building **plug-ins, fragments or features** consists of the 3 stages: fetch, generate scripts and build that are described bellow.

You could have some [issue for modified plugin](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.pde/msg01775.html), but building features or a [final product](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/pde-build-dev/msg00681.html) should work.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. In fact I am stilling having problem and questions.

Using plugins as product base result in an exported (with GUi or headless build, it's the same) with ALL the required plugins (computed I guess through plugins manifest).

On the opposite, when using feature as bases the exported product only contain the listed features in the product file. To work, I have to add manually all the required features. This also has the side effect to bring all the features plugins even if they are not needed. Should I open an other question for that ?

Comment: @Manuel: probably. the context of that new question would be clearer.

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140299/plugin-product-vs-feature-product

Answer (score 0):

Very useful tutorial from ibm for memory leaks in rcp:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-rcp2/index.html