# Export a Plug-In

Tags: eclipse, url, eclipse-plugin, repository, export

I made a plugin in eclipse IDE but is in raw (is not packaged), I want to upload it to a repository so that people can download and install it in your IDE. i.e. they can go to Help-> Install New Software, add a url and download my plug-in. To run my plug-in it uses a grammar made ​​using the xtext modeling tool(plug-in). I dont know if there are any problems if my plug-in have others plug-in dependencies. I searched what could do and I found something related to the creation of PCR products:

*[What are the differences between plug-ins, features, and products in Eclipse RCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692048/what-is-the-differences-between-plug-in-feature-and-product-in-eclipse-rcp)

*http://www.coplec.org/1-creando-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-rcp/07-april-2008

I'm not sure if this help me to do for what I want do. I really appreciate any information about it. Sorry my English i know that is not very good. Ty :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create an [update site to deploy your plugin](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#p2deployplugin). Dependent plugins (like the xtext runtime) should normally not be packaged directly into your feature. If the user checks the "contact all update sites during installation to find dependencies", then your dependencies will be fetched directly from the eclipse servers instead.